# How to alert via email in Ansible

Tags: automation, ansible

I have setup a mail task in ansible to send emails if yum update is marked as 'changed'.

Here is my current working code:

```
- name: Send mail alert if updated
      community.general.mail:
        to:
        - 'recipient1'
        cc:
        - 'recipient2'
        subject: Update Alert
        body: 'Ansible Tower Updates have been applied on the following system: {{ ansible_hostname }}'
        sender: "ansible.updates@domain.com"
      delegate_to: localhost
      when: yum_update.changed
```

This works great, however, every system that gets updated per host group sends a separate email. Last night for instance I had a group of 20 servers update and received 20 separate emails. I'm aware of why this happens, but my question is how would I script this to add all the systems to one email? Is that even possible or should I just alert that the group was updated and inform teams of what servers are in each group? (I'd prefer not to take the second option)

Edit 1:

I have added the code suggested and am now unable to receive any emails. Here's the error message:

```
"msg": "The conditional check '_changed|length > 0' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (_changed|length > 0): {{ hostvars|dict2items| selectattr('value.yum_update.changed')| map(attribute='key')|list }}: 'ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVarsVars object' has no attribute 'yum_update'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/tmp/bwrap_1073_o8ibkgrl/awx_1073_0eojw5px/project/yum-update-ent_template_servers.yml': line 22, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - name: Send mail alert if updated\n      ^ here\n",
```

I am also attaching my entire playbook for reference:

```
---
- name: Update enterprise template servers
  hosts: ent_template_servers

  tasks:

    - name: Update all packages
      yum:
        name: '*'
        state: latest
      register: yum_update

    - name: Reboot if needed
      import_tasks: /usr/share/ansible/tasks/reboot-if-needed-centos.yml

    - name: Kernel Cleanup
      import_tasks: /usr/share/ansible/tasks/kernel-cleanup.yml

    - debug:
        var: yum_update.changed

    - name: Send mail alert if updated
      community.general.mail:
        to:
        - 'email@domain.com'
        subject: Update Alert
        body: |-
          Updates have been applied on the following system(s):
          {{ _changed }}
        sender: "ansible.updates@domain.com"
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
      when: _changed|length > 0
      vars:
        _changed: "{{ hostvars|dict2items|
                      selectattr('yum_update.changed')|
                      map(attribute='key')|list }}"

...
```

Ansible version is: 2.9.27
Ansible Tower version is: 3.8.3

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, the *mail* task below

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: yum_update.changed
    - community.general.mail:
        sender: ansible
        to: root
        subject: Update Alert
        body: |-
          Updates have been applied to the following system:
          {{ _changed }}
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
      when: _changed|length > 0
      vars:
        _changed: "{{ hostvars|dict2items|
                      selectattr('value.yum_update.changed')|
                      map(attribute='key')|list }}"
```

```yaml
TASK [debug] ***************************************************************
ok: [host01] => 
  yum_update.changed: true
ok: [host02] => 
  yum_update.changed: false
ok: [host03] => 
  yum_update.changed: true

TASK [community.general.mail] **********************************************
ok: [host01 -> localhost]
```

will send

```sh
From: ansible@domain.com
To: root@domain.com
Cc: 
Subject: Update Alert
Date: Wed, 09 Feb 2022 16:55:47 +0100
X-Mailer: Ansible mail module

Updates have been applied to the following system:
['host01', 'host03']
```

Remove the condition below if you want to receive also empty lists

```yaml
      when: _changed|length > 0
```

---

**Debug**

> 'ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVarsVars object' has no attribute 'yum_update'

Q: *"**What I could try?**"*

A: Some of the hosts are missing the variables *yum_update*. You can test it

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ hostvars|dict2items|
                 selectattr('value.yum_update.changed')|
                 map(attribute='key')|list }}"
      run_once: true
```

Either make sure that the variable is defined on all hosts or use *json_query*. This filter tolerates missing attributes, e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ hostvars|dict2items|
                 json_query('[?value.yum_update.changed].key') }}"
      run_once: true
```

---

Q: **"*The 'debug' task prior to the 'mail' task gives me the same output. But it fails when the 'mail' task is executed.*"**

A: Minimize the code and isolate the problem. For example, in the code below you can see

- Variable *yum_update.changed* is missing on *host03*
- The filter *json_query* ignores this
- The filter *selectattr* fails

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: yum_update.changed

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ hostvars|dict2items|
                 json_query('[?value.yum_update.changed].key') }}"
      run_once: true

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ hostvars|dict2items|
                 selectattr('value.yum_update.changed')|
                 map(attribute='key')|list }}"
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] **************************************************
ok: [host01] => 
  yum_update.changed: true
ok: [host02] => 
  yum_update.changed: false
ok: [host03] => 
  yum_update.changed: VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!

TASK [debug] **************************************************
ok: [host01] => 
  msg:
  - host01

TASK [debug] **************************************************
fatal: [host01]: FAILED! => 
  msg: |-
    The task includes an option with an undefined variable.
    The error was: 'ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVarsVars object'
    has no attribute 'yum_update'
```

Both filters give the same results if all variables are present

```yaml
TASK [debug] **************************************************
ok: [host01] => 
  yum_update.changed: true
ok: [host02] => 
  yum_update.changed: false
ok: [host03] => 
  yum_update.changed: true

TASK [debug] **************************************************
ok: [host01] => 
  msg:
  - host01
  - host03

TASK [debug] **************************************************
ok: [host01] => 
  msg:
  - host01
  - host03
```

Comment: It looks like based on the errors I'm seeing, the 'vars' aren't being populated properly. I'm researching what's going on, but wondered if maybe you had thoughts on what I could try? I did attach my full playbook just in case something I have there is making this not work correctly. Thank you.

Comment: The error is clear. The variable *yum_update* is missing. I updated the answer.

Comment: Right, my question now is why the variable is missing? I don't understand what's different in my playbook vs your example. The 'debug' task prior to the 'mail' task gives me the same output that you have shown, but then when the mail task is executed it fails. Regardless of the output of the 'yum' task, I have it set to register to the variable `yum_update` so there shouldn't be any hosts with that variable missing, yet there are as stated by the error. Apologies for my ignorance, I do appreciate the help here as this will be really great once it is working properly for me.

Comment: You must be missing something trivial. I updated the debug part. Open new question if you still have problems. Make it [mre]!

Comment: I believe this issue lies somehow with the inventories I'm using in Ansible Tower. The host in the example is selected out of a dynamic inventory imported from VMware When I tried to view the hostvars, I noticed it was outputting entries for every host in the inventory. When I segregated the host to it's own inventory, the script ran with no issue.

Comment: You have to understand that nobody cares about this ballast (Tower, dynamic inventory, VMware, ...). SO is Q&A site. The question of how ``to add all the systems to one email`` was answered. The case is closed.  **Please, open a new question if you still have problems. Make it a [mre]!**